# Website Layout Is Not Perfect In UC Mini Browser , Why?

Tags: html, css

Here is my website , http://akhil.djmusicweb.com , in all major browser except UC browser for mobile , website layout is as per the html and css code , but in UC mini browser , its very bad layout , how to solve this , please help :( ?

Answer (score 0):

Please use Percentage instead of Pixel in your CSS, and also control it via min-width and min-height, SO that Uc mini Browser can handle it easily

Comment: ya , its percent based layout because website is responsive , but still uc mini browser gives bad layout :( , why ?